# Reason for error using select statement containing aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone explain why the following query throws an error, if I am trying to get the names of all customers along with the total number of customers?

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM CUSTOMER
```

I know that selecting columns along with an aggregate function requires a GROUP BY statement containing all the column names, but I don't understand the logical principle behind this.

edit:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90233/595
I guess 'error' isn't quite right, but notice how the current query returns Allison 9 as the only result.
I don't understand why it doesn't return:

Alison 9

Alison 9

Alison 9

Alison 9

Jason 9

...

Comment: Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  In its default configuration, MySQL would not generate an error.

Comment: actually I believe it would return the total count alongside the first customer name. What we want is the full list of customer names each with the total customer count alongside it. So I don't understand why the full customer name list is collapsed when using the aggregate Count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is a new answer based on the comment and looking at the fiddle.)

The issue here is how mysql handles aggregate functions -- which is a non-standard way and different then everyone else.

mysql lets you use aggregate functions (count() is an example of an aggregate function) without a group by.  All (or most?) other sql implementations require the group by when you use count(*).  When you have a group by you have to say the range in the group by (for example group by name).  **Also** every column has to be in the range or the result of an aggregate function.

SINCE you don't have a range mysql assumes the whole table and since you have a column that is not the result of a aggregate function or in the range (in this case name) mysql does something to make that column the result of an aggregate function.  I'm not sure if it is specified in mysql what it does -- lets say "max()".  (Fairly sure it is max()).  So the real sql that is getting executed is

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(name), COUNT(*)
FROM CUSTOMER
```

Thus you only see one name.

mysql documentation - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

*After reading the above I see that mysql will use the default aggregate function `ANY_VALUE()` for columns which are not in the range.*

---

If you just want the total number of customers on each row you could do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, COUNT(NAME) OVER () AS CustomerCount
FROM CUSTOMER
```

In this way you don't need the GROUP BY syntax.  Under the covers it is probably doing the same thing as @GordonLinoff 's answer.

I added this because maybe it makes it clearer how group by works.

Comment: again though, my question is about why my query returns "Alison 9" rather than the full list of names, each with the total row count.

Comment: @nsledeski - I understand your question now see edit

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name, Count(*) as 'CountCustomers'
FROM CUSTOMER
Group by name
Order by name
```

Think of it as giving an instruction of which field to aggregate by.  For example, if you had a field with the State of the Customer, you could group by State which would give a count of customers by state.

Also, note you can have multiple aggregate functions in the same select using the "over (partition by"  construct.

Comment: This is wrong this would give how many rows a given customer has in the table -- exactly the problem the OP was asking to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the names along with the *total* number of customers, then use a window function:

```
select name, count(*) as NumCustomersWithName,
       sum(count(*)) over () as NumCustomers
from customer
group by name;
```

Edit:

You actually seem to want:

```
select name, count(*) over () as NumCustomers
from customer;
```

In MySQL, you would do this with a subquery:

```
select name, cnt
from customers cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from customers) x;
```

The reason your query doesn't work is because it is an aggregation query that returns exactly one row.  When you use aggregation functions without a `GROUP BY`, then the query always returns exactly one row.

Comment: my question isn't about how to find the right result, it's why my original code returns the wrong one

Comment: @nsledeski . . . What is the result you actually want?  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - you didn't look at the fiddle, this is a mysql issue.

Comment: @Hogan . . . (1) I did look at the SQL Fiddle; (2) I do include MySQL in the answer; (3) SQL Fiddle defaults to MySQL, so new users often given examples using MySQL even when it is not the database; (4) The original question specified an *error*, which MySQL does not generate on the code (wrong answer maybe but not an error).

Comment: @GordonLinoff - good point.  The comment on my answer made it clear that even if the user is not using mysql, why the fiddle gave the results it did was of concern. :D